# Al momento de mostrar los datos finales en C

Tags: c, printf

Ya Que tengo una variable con datos almacenados y la intento mostrar en un printf no me salen los datos si no que sale un numero que nada tiene que ver.

totalcasados es variable entera (int).

```
printf("Total de Casados: %d",&totalcasados);
```

deberia mostrar un numero menor de 15 y muestra "733245"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mostrando la dirección de memoria (puntero) en lugar del valor de tu variable. Quita el ampersand:

```
printf("Total de Casados: %d", totalcasados);
```

Comment: Ya se lo quite pero sale 0, aun cuando los contadores ya habian  incrementado.

Comment: Entonces es que ese valor es 0. Revisa tu código (podrías ampliar el código que nuestras acá). Prueba ir simplificando tu código, por ejemplo asignándole un valor justo en la línea anterior, y a partir de ahí busca. El depurador te puede ayudar también.